# ldconfig loading only .so files

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, snort

I'm trying run a program(Snort) that uses libdnet but it fails to find it and outputs:

> snort: error while loading shared libraries: libdnet.1: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory

Now I know that I should add the library by running `ldconfig` and putting path to the library in `/etc/ld.so.conf`. libdnet is located in `/usr/local/lib` so I don't have to modify `ld.so.conf` since [it already covers that dirctory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12234010/279982). So I ran the following commands and tracing the output, I noticed my library is not being loaded.

```
ldconfig -v
```

Apparently ldconfig only loads files that have `.so` somewhere in their names and `libdnet.1` doesn't match the pattern.
I've built libdnet from source and installed it using `./configure; make; make install` commands. I'd rather not install it using the package manager unless I have to. What should I do?

**EDIT:**
It says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11843480/279982) that libraries should match the patter `lib*.so*` but I can't rename the library. I neither made it nor am I using it in my own app: if I rename it it will be loaded but I think Snort is looking for `libdnet.1` not `libdnet.so.1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/honeyd-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libdnet-1-cannot-open-shared-object-fi-885653/#post4557734). The Solution was simple: make a copy that matches the pattern.

```
cp /usr/local/lib/libdnet.1.0.1 /usr/local/lib/libdnet.so.1.0.1
```

A less preferred [alternative](http://www.ashishnepal.com/snort-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libdnet-1/):

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```